# Object reference equals check for LRU Cache implementation

Tags: java, object, hashmap, equals, lru

My understanding of Java for equals is that if two objects have the same reference, they are equal via ==. If it's a String for example, you need to use the .equals() to compare the values;

The code below is a sample LRUCache. In the addToEnd method, at one point I compare the tail to the node (where it says do nothing), and even though they have the same reference they do not hit that block of code. Can someone please explain why? When debugging they have the exact same reference.

```
public class LRUCache {

    private class Node {
        private int key;
        private int value;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        private Node (int key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private Map<Integer, Node> lookup;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.lookup = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
    }

    private void addToEnd(Node node) {
        if (node == this.tail) {
            //do nothing
        }
        if (this.tail != null) {
            if (node == this.head) {
                this.head = this.head.next;
            }
            Node prev = node.prev;
            Node next = node.next;
            if (prev != null) {
                prev.next = next;
            }

            if (next != null) {
                next.prev = prev;
            }
            this.tail.next = node;
            node.prev = this.tail;
            node.next = null;
            this.tail = node;
        } else {
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = this.head;
        }
    }

    private void popHead() {
        if (this.head != null) {
            this.lookup.remove(this.head.key);
            Node node = this.head.next;
            this.head = node;
            this.size--;
        }
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if (lookup.containsKey(key)) {
            Node node = lookup.get(key);
            addToEnd(node);
            return node.value;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        if (lookup.containsKey(key)) {
            Node node = lookup.get(key);
            addToEnd(node);
            node.value = value;
            return;
        } else if (this.size == this.capacity) {
            popHead();
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(key, value);
        addToEnd(newNode);
        this.lookup.put(key, newNode);
        this.size++;
    }
}
```

And here's the code I ran:

```
       LRUCache lRUCache = new LRUCache(1);
       lRUCache.put(2, 1);
       lRUCache.get(2); 
       lRUCache.put(3, 2); 
       System.out.println(lRUCache.get(2)); //getting 1 but should be -1
       System.out.println(lRUCache.get(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
        if (node == this.tail) {
            //do nothing
        }
```

The intention might be to do nothing and return

The `return` keyword is missing.

So, adding `return` should give correct behavior

```java
        if (node == this.tail) {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used the debugger with return and it hit it.